# Qual é o objetivo dessa linguagem chamada Brainfuck?

Tags: brainfuck

Existe uma linguagem de programação chamada [Brainfuck](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) que tem uma sintaxe bem confusa e de difícil compreensão.

Por exemplo, para se fazer um simples `Hello World` na mesma, você tem que fazer o seguinte:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

Vendo essa pequena "string", podemos perceber o porquê do nome da linguagem.

Então, levando em consideração a difícil sintaxe da linguagem (e o nome), gostaria de saber qual é o objetivo da existência da mesma?

Isso é  uma brincadeira que fizeram ou essa linguagem realmente pode ser usada para construção de aplicações?

Mais um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O objetivo já é descrito pelo nome da linguagem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Essa linguagem faz parte de um conjunto de linguagens que tem mais aplicações teóricas que práticas. [Da Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) (tradução livre):

> Apesar de ser equivalente à máquina de Turing, [a linguagem] não foi desenvolvida para aplicações práticas, mas apenas para **desafiar e entreter** os programadores.

É um tipo de brincadeira, mas como ela é *Turing complete*, pode ser usado para criar qualquer aplicação (não que alguém vá fazer isso na prática). Você vai achar vários exemplos de sua utilização no [*Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=brainfuck).

Comment: **Brainfuck** é a segunda linguagem de programação mais fodástica que existe no contexto de ser *Turing complete*. A mais foda de todas é outra que surgiu a partir dela, a **Boolfuck**.