# O que é a Máquina de Turing?

Tags: terminologia, teoria-da-computação

O que é essa tal Máquina de Turing que o fez o Turing ser reconhecido como o "Pai da Computação"? Como é o seu funcionamento e como ela faz pra ler uma fita de binários?

Comment: Onde ele é conhecido como o pai da computação ?

Comment: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=pai+da+computacao&oq=pai+da+computacao&aqs=chrome..69i57.2527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Mas acredito que o termo mais correto seria, pai da criptografia moderna :)

Comment: Será que é duplicata dessa? (que consideraram duplicata e eu achei que não é, mas não vou mexer por conta própria) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101. Relacionadas ou pelo menos que fazem citações práticas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101683/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99642/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7740/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113985/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28297/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30749/101, entre outras

Comment: A pergunta é boa, mas acho ser duplicata sim :P

Comment: Acredito que o termo seja usado muito como licença poética. É complicado fazer tal afirmação quando na verdade várias pessoas contribuíram muito para a base da computação moderna, uma sem a outra não serviria para nada do que temos hoje.

Comment: @bigown acho que essa sua resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35548/14262 já responde essa pergunta

Comment: Talvez o que salve a pergunta seja "Como é o seu funcionamento e como ela faz pra ler uma fita de binários?"

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não sei, vamos ver o que outras pessoas acham, pode ser que possa sair algo mais específico. Talvez a segunda parte caiba sozinha.

Comment: Concordo que a pergunta é boa (a parte funcional)... E levando em consideração a colocação do @bigown, fico confortável com o termo "um dos Pais"...

Comment: So lembrando que a maquina de turing corroborou para a [criação de uma das áreas mais importantes e complexas da computação](http://www.ufrgs.br/alanturingbrasil2012/Maquina_de_Turing.pdf) (autômatos), dai para o porque ele é considerado "um dos" pais da computação moderna, não da pra atribuir todo o estado da arte como sendo obra somente dele, tivemos outras grandes mentes na evolução da computação, vide George Boole, Von_Neumann, entre outros

Comment: @bigown eu acho que o mais próximo que essas respostas devem estar é uma que diz que a linguagem tem que obedecer uma maquina de turing, mas o que é e como ela funciona eu não acho que essas perguntas respondem. MarceloBonifazio, eu penso que pai remete à ideia de ser um só... mas concordo que podem haver controvérsias à esse título e que ele seja polêmico

Comment: Para quem gosta de assistir Faustão no Domingo, fica a dica : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqzuLlY6cJA

Comment: http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html

Comment: @guijob a resposta aceita foi apagada porque é plágio. Se tiver interesse, agora tem outra resposta se quiser aceitá-la.

Answer (score 5):

[Segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) a Máquina de Turing é um modelo matemático de computação que descreve uma máquina abstrata que manipula símbolos em uma fita de acordo com uma tabela de regras. Apesar da simplicidade do modelo, ele é capaz de implementar qualquer algoritmo de computador.

Em termos bem leigos é a forma como uma pessoa resolve um problema matemático.

Note que não o termo não se refere a uma máquina real, embora possamos construir uma máquina que atende o modelo que ela define. Ou quase, já que ela prega memória infinita, o que não é possível no mundo real.

Em 1936 o termo **algoritmo** foi formalizado como sendo um conjunto finito de instruções simples e precisas, que são descritas com um número finito de símbolos.

Qualquer dispositivo, seja hardware ou software, que se conforme com o modelo definido pelo [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing), seu criador, pode ser considerado um dispositivo [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), portanto ele atende aos critérios da Máquina de Turing. A ideia do algoritmo iniciou-se a partir daí através da proposição de [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church):

> Qualquer processo aceito por nós homens como um algoritmo é precisamente o que uma máquina de Turing pode fazer

Estritamente falando nada real pode ser Turing Complete, então a infinitude costuma ser desconsiderada.

De fato, algumas máquinas foram produzidas para demonstrar o conceito.

[image: Máquina de Turing]

Seguindo a Wikipedia, a máquina opera em uma fita de memória infinita dividida em células discretas, cada uma das quais pode conter um único símbolo extraído de um conjunto finito de símbolos chamado *alfabeto da máquina*. Possui uma "cabeça" que, em qualquer ponto da operação da máquina, é posicionada sobre uma dessas células, e um "estado" selecionado a partir de um conjunto finito de estados. A cada passo de sua operação, a cabeça lê o símbolo em sua célula. Então, com base no símbolo e no estado atual da própria máquina, a máquina escreve um símbolo na mesma célula e move a cabeça um passo para a esquerda ou para a direita, ou interrompe a computação. A escolha de qual símbolo de substituição escrever e qual direção mover é baseada em uma tabela finita que especifica o que fazer para cada combinação do estado atual e o símbolo que é lido.

Se desejar [pode experimentar a máquina virtualmente](https://turingmachine.io/).

O modelo foi importante para que o Turing tivesse um parâmetro do que faria para atingir os objetivos da criação de um computador, como é o computador moderno que usamos hoje.

Dispositivos de software podem se conformar com a Máquina de Turing também. E de fato a definição d[o que é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) passou adotar essa capacidade, já que a Máquina de Turing é capaz de executar computações arbitrárias, exatamente o que se espera de uma linguagem de programação, que vai além do que outras linguagens mais simples podem oferecer. Alguns [testes podem ser feitos para determinar isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101683/101). Exemplo de [linguagem que não passa no teste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101), sendo que universalmente temos o [Teste de Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test). E [um que passa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99642/101). A linguagem pode ser fora do comum ou ser [inútil na prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113985/101). Pode-se ver [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28297/101). [Também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30749/101).

Existem variantes da máquina para atender cenários específicos, e justamente uma variante que aceita a finitude é usada na maioria dos casos. É possível ter máquinas determinísticas e não determinísticas, ter mais de uma fita, etc.

Daí surgiu a [Teoria dos Autômatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) e o [Problema da Condição de Parada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

[image: Teroria de autônomos]

Ainda que existam pessoas que dizem que não é a completeza de Turing que define o que é uma linguagem de programação, há muito material e apoio dessa ideia, e nenhuma ideia superior claramente é apresentada para dar uma definição melhor.

Como não é fácil fazer uma demonstração do funcionamento da MT e para não incorrer em plágio, como a outra resposta existente (quem sabe não mais quando ler isso), vou deixar alguns *links* que pode ajudar:

- http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/6/61/MT1_2011.pdf
- https://epxx.co/artigos/touring.html
- [https://webpages.ciencias.ulisboa.pt/~ommartins/seminario/vonnewman/NetMenu/maquina_de_turing.htm](https://webpages.ciencias.ulisboa.pt/%7Eommartins/seminario/vonnewman/NetMenu/maquina_de_turing.htm)
- http://www.decom.ufop.br/anderson/2_2011/BCC244/MaquinasDeTuring.pdf