# A linguagem SQL é orientada a objetos?

Tags: sql, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem

A linguagem SQL é orientada a objetos? Se sim, poderia mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Não, sql é linguagem para manipulação de banco de dados relacional. Uma definição melhor : 

SQL é uma linguagem padronizada para a definição e manipulação de bancos de dados relacionais. Tipicamente, um SGBD oferece um interpretador SQL que permite isolar a aplicação dos detalhes de armazenamento dos dados. ... uma linguagem de manipulação de dados (DML) para ler e escrever os dados. by google

Comment: Definitivamente não. É uma linguagem para expressar cálculo relacional.

Answer (score 22):

**SQL** significa *Structured Query Language*, ou seja, trata-se de uma linguagem estruturada, específica para manipulação em banco de dados relacionais (seja SQL Server, MySQL, etc).

Portanto, não há suporte para orientação a objetos nela.

Existe também o **NoSQL**, que alguns chamam de *Not Only Structured Query Language* e outros de *Non Structured Query Language*, que utiliza outros modelos de dados, tais como Documentos e Gráficos.

> Os bancos de dados NoSQL usam diversos modelos de dados, incluindo documentos, gráficos, chave-valor e colunares.

Fonte: [Amazon NoSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/nosql/).

Ainda assim, eu não considero como uma linguagem que ofereça orientação a objetos, pois para isso, ela precisaria ter suporte a herança, encapsulamento e polimorfismo, que são conceitos da Orientação a Objetos.

Answer (score 21):

Ela sequer é uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Então não caberia analisar se ela possui mecanismos de linguagens de programação orientada a objeto. Ela não suporta [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) típicos de linguagens de programação. Ela não possui todas as capacidades de uma [Máquina de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158043/101).

Apesar do nome incluir a palavra estruturada, também nada tem a ver com o paradigma de [programação estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101).

Ela não possui nenhum dos [pilares da orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101) que são herança, encapsulamento e polimorfismo. Ela não possui [objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) propriedade ditos, por isso não pode ser [orientada a eles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). Orientação exige muito mais que uma linguagem de programação básica oferece e SQL nem o básico oferece.

SQL, como o nome diz, é uma linguagens de consultas, ela é puramente [declarativa e não imperativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81857/101). Então é possível apenas declarar intenções. Claro que além de consultas podemos fazer atualizações e modelar como queremos o banco de dados, mas não podemos fazer operações estruturadas, não podemos comandar tudo como queremos fazendo algoritmos completos, muito menos podemos estruturar objetos como definido em OOP.

Algumas linguagens baseadas em SQL como T-SQL do SQL Server ou PL/SQL do Oracle e outros são consideradas linguagens de programação, mesmo assim não possuem mecanismos de orientação a objeto. Ao contrário de [C que tem alguns mecanismos que permitem fazer um código OO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101) quase ilegível, estas linguagens não possuem nada que auxiliem isto e torna-se praticamente impossível a adoção do paradigma. Talvez alguma forma bem maluca, mas teria enormes malefícios.

Alguém pode questionar se é possível adotar um modelo orientado a objeto em SQL. A resposta seria não, mas é possível adotar um modelo orientado a objeto nas tabelas do banco de dados, que é diferente do SQL. Mesmo que o banco de dados não ofereça muitos recursos ainda é possível de alguma forma, não totalmente, talvez nem em todos bancos de dados. Alguns DBs oferecem facilidades que dá para modelar as tabelas como objetos, mas não o SQL.

Isso faz todo sentido porque OO tem a ver com organização da estrutura de dados mais que a programação em si.

Adicionalmente, NoSQL é um modelo de acesso, sequer é uma linguagem, então não cabe comparações.

Orientação a objeto é superestimada. Hoje é moda todo mundo querer fazer OO mesmo sem saber sequer se terá benefícios com isto. Na verdade é comum as pessoas dizerem que estão fazendo e nem estão, só para estar na moda. Uma "metodologia" deve ser adotada para algum benefício, e só depois de dominá-la, o que no caso de OO não é fácil.

Complemento: [POO é igual em todas as linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213951/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Só complementando que o PL/SQL já possui implementação de Orientação a Objetos, e muito bem, obrigado. Antes, com as packages, conseguá-se simular, até certo ponto, uma "Classe", agora já se pode criar realmente uma Classe, com seus métodos, propriedades, e tudo que tem direito, e com isso, um objeto dela, para manipularmos dentro de outras Classes e/ou outras Packages e/ou Procedures e/ou Functions. Isso é o grande barato hoje da PL/SQL, porque podemos ter objetos da camada de negócio, cujos métodos podem executar códigos em métodos de objetos de Classes definidas em PL/SQL mesmo. Com isso o código em PL/SQL ficou bem mais limpo e simples de entender depois.